# Iphone 2d game - Applying Gravity , Bounce issue

Tags: objective-c, c, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

Am a flash game developer at present I started writing games for iphone using cocos 2d engine, I have implemented separate Axis theorem for collision detection which works perfect.  All the polygons are drawn as follows in openGl. 
Now am trying to apply gravity to this 16x16 box after many search I found this tutorial http://www.seinia.com/tutorials/Bounce/ and implemented the same in objective C.

The problem am having is after the square comes to rest it keeps bouncing up/down in fractions. I tried a lot to fix this but I couldn't control that tiny movement.I never had such problem in flash but here the floating value is affecting the square position a lot.

Please let me know what is the write way to handle such issue , any reference URL would be helpful. Appriciated your help.Thanks!

```
0,16        16,16 

 ------------
|            |
|            |
|            |
|            |       
 ------------

0,0          16,0
```

Objective C code

```
if (square.points[0].y <= 0.1f) {
        velocity.vy *= -bounce;
        [square restInPeace:[Vector2D createVectorWithComponentX:velocity.vx Y:8.0f]];
        // landed
        if (fabs(velocity.vy) < 0.9f) {
            velocity.vy = 0.0f;
            [square restInPeace:[Vector2D createVectorWithComponentX:velocity.vx Y:8.0f]];
            isLanded = YES;
        }   
    }
```

**Translate the object**

```
-(void) translateVelocity:(Vector2D*)velocity
{   
    // The center as well as all of the vertices need to be
    // accommodated.
    center.x += velocity.vx;
    center.y += velocity.vy;

    for(int i=0; i < count; i++)
    {
        points[i].x += velocity.vx;
        points[i].y += velocity.vy;

        ////NSLog(@"velocity %f %f",points[i].x , points[i].y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly it would be easer to use Box2D phys engine coming with cocos2d...

Comment: Exactly you are correct , but reason for implementing everything my own is because am searching for Job so rite now.I thought writing from the scratch would be helpful to refresh the basics , vector math , collision.

Comment: @JustJeff : sorry I missed it , now I have added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a bounce algorithm, it is usually recommended to implement a slight imperfection to make sure that this event does not happen. You could also largen the range of what is accepted as "Landed", but remember to make sure that you then stick the object to the floor to make sure there are no visual artifacts.

By the imperfection I mean :

```
velocity.vy *= (-bounce + 0.01f);
```

For example. This should make your object always come to a halt.

Comment: Still having the same issue , now I decided to compromise the bounce so I want to implement just the gravity alone for now. I mean once it hits the ground I want to keep the square in ground. A new problem am having now is setting the coordinates to make them stay on the ground , the gravity keep pulling the square down and in few seconds the square is moving out of the bounding box.

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem. I'm guessing you're applying gravity to the four points, and when one hits the ground you stop it. To keep the object size, either you say that the object is completely rigid, in which case the positions of the other points will be absolute, or you can implement a spring type connection between the points to maintain the shape.
Each corner should be attached to each other corner.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - Actually am struggling in implementing very basic gravity. I did a mistake while updating the landing position , I fixed that now both bounce & gravity is also working. Thanks a lot for your time , which really make me think.